# How to create customer via customer repository in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, customer, api, service-contract

To create customer via Magento 2 services from php client
i have used two files

**test.php**

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('TestApp');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

**testapp.php**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http as RequestHttp;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as ResponseHttp;
use Magento\Framework\Event;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\AreaList;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

class TestApp extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository
     */
    protected $_customerRepository;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
     */
    protected $_customerInterface;

    protected $_customInterface;


    public function launch()
    {   
        $response = $this->test();

        echo get_class($response);

        return $this->_response;
    }

    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected $customer_Repository;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param Event\Manager $eventManager
     * @param AreaList $areaList
     * @param RequestHttp $request
     * @param ResponseHttp $response
     * @param ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader
     * @param State $state
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
     \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository $customer_Repository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customerInterface
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        Event\Manager $eventManager,
        AreaList $areaList,
        RequestHttp $request,
        ResponseHttp $response,
        ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader,
        State $state,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,        
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository $customer_Repository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customerInterface
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_areaList = $areaList;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->_configLoader = $configLoader;
        $this->_state = $state;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->customer_Repository = $customer_Repository;
        $this->_customerInterface = $customerInterface;
    }

    public function test(){     

        $customer_1 = array(
                /*"id"=> 0,
                "groupId"=> 0,
                "defaultBilling"=>"string",
                "defaultShipping"=> "string",
                "confirmation"=> "string",
                "createdAt"=> "",
                "updatedAt"=> "",
                "createdIn"=> "",
                "dob"=> "",*/
                "email"=> "magento_one@gmail.com",
                "firstname"=> "magento",
                "lastname"=> "one",
                "middlename"=> "",
                "prefix"=> "",
                "suffix"=> "",
                "gender"=> 0,
                "storeId"=> 1,
                "taxvat"=> "1236547890",
                "websiteId"=> 1,
                "addresses" => array(
                    array(
                    //"id"=> 0,
                    "customerId" => 0,
                    "region" => array(
                        "regionCode"=> "CA",
                        "region"=> "California",
                        "regionId"=> 12,
                        //"extensionAttributes" => array()
                    ),
                    //"regionId"=> 0,
                    "countryId"=> "US",
                    "street" => array(
                        "Zoe Ave"
                    ),
                    "company"=> "bcd",
                    "telephone"=> "555-000-00-00",
                    "fax"=> "555-000-00-00",
                    "postcode"=> "90001",
                    "city"=> "Los Angeles",
                    "firstname"=> "Magento",
                    "lastname"=> "One",
                    "middlename"=> "",
                    "prefix"=> "",
                    "suffix"=> "",
                    "vatId"=> "1234567890",
                    "defaultShipping"=> true,
                    "defaultBilling"=> true,
                    /*"extensionAttributes"=> array(),
                    "customAttributes" => array(
                          "attributeCode"=> "",
                          "value"=> ""
                    )*/
                    ),
                ),
                /* "disableAutoGroupChange"=> 0,
                 "extensionAttributes"=> array(

                 ),
                 "customAttributes" => array(

                 )*/
            //"passwordHash" => "Pass@word1"
        );

        $customer_2 = array(
            "customer" => array(
                /*"id"=> 0,
                "groupId"=> 0,
                "defaultBilling"=>"",
                "defaultShipping"=> "",
                "confirmation"=> "",
                "createdAt"=> "",
                "updatedAt"=> "",
                "createdIn"=> "",
                "dob"=> "",*/
                "email"=> "magento_two@gmail.com",
                "firstname"=> "Magento",
                "lastname"=> "Two",
                "middlename"=> "",
                "prefix"=> "",
                "suffix"=> "",
                "gender"=> 0,
                "storeId"=> 1,
                "taxvat"=> "555-000-00-00",
                "websiteId"=> 1,
                "addresses" => array(
                    //"id"=> 0,
                    "customerId"=> 0,
                    "region" => array(
                        //"regionCode"=> "string",
                        "region"=> "New York",
                        //"regionId"=> 0,
                        // "extensionAttributes" => array()
                    ),
                    //"regionId"=> 0,
                    "countryId"=> "US",
                    "street" => array(
                        "786 Unit"
                    ),
                    "company"=> "abc",
                    "telephone"=> "555-000-00-00",
                    "fax"=> "555-000-00-00",
                    "postcode"=> "10004",
                    "city"=> "New York",
                    "firstname"=> "Magento",
                    "lastname"=> "Two",
                    "middlename"=> "",
                    "prefix"=> "",
                    "suffix"=> "",
                    "vatId"=> "1235498970",
                    "defaultShipping"=> true,
                    "defaultBilling"=> true,
                    /*"extensionAttributes"=> array(),
                    "customAttributes" => array(
                        "attributeCode"=> "",
                        "value"=> ""
                    )*/
                ),
                /*"disableAutoGroupChange"=> 0,
                "extensionAttributes"=> array(

                ),
                "customAttributes" => array(

                )*/
            ),
            //"passwordHash" => "Pass@word1"
        );


        $customer = array("customer1" => $customer_1);

        foreach($customer as $customers){
            try
            {
                foreach($customers as $key => $value){

                    $field = 'set' . $key;
                    $this->_customerInterface->$field($value);
                }
                $customer_data = $this->customer_Repository->save($this->_customerInterface);

                //$customer_data = $this->customerRepository->save($customers);

            }catch (\Exception $ex){
                $var = $ex;
                //$this->_logger->info($ex->getMessage());
                continue;
            }
        }
}
}
```

If I do not specify `addresses` element then its working fine, if I specify the `addresses` element it gives me following error :

> Call to a member function setCustomerId() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\M2EE\vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository.php on line 212

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CustomerInterface` is [non-injectable](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html#dep-inj-mod-type-life-mgmt) and should not be injected in the construct directly, inject factory instead. It is possible to use `populateWithArray` like is done in `\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor::extract`.

Comment: if possible can you explain how should i use `extract` in my case

Comment: You should not use `extract`, just look how `$customerDataObject` is populated in that method, that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: after calling populateWithArray how should i invoke save method

Comment: Use `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface::save`, which accepts customer interface and password hash.

Answer (score 4):

The following code (for Magento 2.1) uses:

`\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory` for create
`\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` for save

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require '/www/mag2.local/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);   
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

### Setting area code
### NOTE: for more info http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_and_areas.html
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('base');

createCustomer();

function createCustomer() {
        global $objectManager;

        $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        $storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();

        $websiteId = $storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId();

        ###
        $customer = null;

        try{
                $customer = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory')->create();
                $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

                ### Preparing data for new customer
                $email = 'test11@example.com';
                $customer->setEmail($email);
                $customer->setFirstname("test first");
                $customer->setLastname("test last");
                $hashedPassword = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface')->getHash('MyNewPass', true);

                ### Save data
                $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->save($customer, $hashedPassword);

                ### Reload customer data
                $customer = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory')->create();
                $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->loadByEmail($email);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
                // stored in var/log/debug.log
                #$objectManager->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->addDebug($e->getMessage());

                // stored in var/log/exception.log
                $objectManager->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->addCritical($e);

                Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
        }

        ### Add address   
        if ($customer->getId()) {
                echo 'Succesfully Saved. Customer ID: ' . $customer->getId();
                echo PHP_EOL;

                try{
                    ### Add Address For created customer
                    $address = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory')->create();

                    $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                        ->setFirstname('test first')
                        ->setLastname('test last')
                        ->setCountryId('US')
                        ->setRegionId('62') //state/province, only needed if the country is USA
                        ->setPostcode('98248')
                        ->setCity('Ferndale')
                        ->setTelephone('7781234567')
                        ->setFax('7781234567')
                        ->setCompany('test company')
                        ->setStreet(['test street'])
                        ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
                        ->setIsDefaultShipping('1');

                    $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface')->save($address);
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                        Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: How it is achieved using AddressRepositoryInterface?

Comment: How to create customer with customAttributes?